# Error: Could not find or load main class MyApp (running java on Command Prompt)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I would like to compile and execute a program in Java with Command Prompt but only compile the program: `javac MyApp.java`

Then I want to execute with that command: `java MyApp` but it throws an **error**:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyApp
```

I think that is possible to be a problem with JRE or JDK configuration but I check the path, `java -version` and 'Build path' in eclipse project but nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Check your [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). That determines where Java looks for the compiled `.class` files.

Comment: Your class MyApp has a public static void main(String[] args){} function inside?

Comment: @punseti yes with simple hello world for testing :)

Comment: Ok @khelwood, but I don't find the command. The link is for set a classpath

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to add to your classpath the directory of MyApp.class. Try this at the command prompt

```
          java -cp . MyApp
```

EDIT

You have to create a folder named 'ok' and you have to put MyApp.class inside that folder.
Then in the parent folder of the ok folder execute

```
          java -cp . ok.MyApp
```

Maybe even `java ok.MyApp` should work

Comment: I tried but throws the same error: `Error: Could not find or load main class MyApp` :/

Comment: @NeilPlain Do you have a package declaration inside MyApp.java?

Comment: @NeilPlain but did you execute the command from the parent directory of 'ok'? (as i wrote on my last edit). On my filesystem I have 'C:\prova\ok\MyApp.class' and I executed the command from 'C:\prova\

Comment: Solved. I was writing the command into package folder. And I tried into 'src' folder and solved! Thanks at all.